# Ubuntu Linux 32bit - not a Genymotion virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

since 4 days i have a problem with my genymotion without found a solution
i am working on ubuntu 12.04 32bit(architecure: i686) and install android studio and put plugin of genymotion in it succefully...now my problem when click on genymotion device manager,the list is empty and when i try to click on "new" i have nothing
and i have this in the log
*

> Listing virtual machines and found Genymotion virtual device...
>              9:42:21 AM Genymotion: Virtual machine found: linux-andr [64ef4d4a-35b9-440d-aea9-45df03783bcd]
>   9:42:21 AM Genymotion: Checking virtual machine...
>   9:42:21 AM Genymotion: Launch process: VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate 64ef4d4a-35b9-440d-aea9-45df03783bcd
>   9:42:22 AM Genymotion: [ERROR] 64ef4d4a-35b9-440d-aea9-45df03783bcd: not a Genymotion virtual device
>   9:42:22 AM Genymotion: Virtual machine found: android-dev [2b516266-b9a7-440e-922c-bf246fc8a65d]
>   9:42:22 AM Genymotion: Checking virtual machine...
>   9:42:22 AM Genymotion: Launch process: VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate 2b516266-b9a7-440e-922c-bf246fc8a65d
>   9:42:22 AM Genymotion: [ERROR] 2b516266-b9a7-440e-922c-bf246fc8a65d: not a Genymotion virtual device*

[image]

please, what can be the problem?

Comment: open genymotion in normal way, I mean: not through a plugin. Try to add new Genymotion emulator. Can you do this? Or you see another error?

Comment: thank you to reply me ...i try by clicking on icon genymotion but it don't open(nothing appear)..i don't know if because my ubuntu is 32bit and the genymotion downloaded ist for the ubuntu 64bit....in the genymotion site i have see only the 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

`Genymotion` emulator nowadays doesn't support 32-bit operational systems.

The last version with 32-bit support was `2.4.0`, but I don't recommend you to install it, as it may not have virtual devices with 5.0 and higher Android version.\

Try to use Android Studio's Android Virtual Devices, but...

Instead of using emulator on 32-bit, which might be very painful on this kind of machine, consider buying a cheap Android device, you don't need to have top phone if you're starting your Android journey.

Hope it will help

Comment: if you feel that it is a correct answer, please don't bother to mark it as answer for another users with the same problem looking for right answer

Answer (score 0):

you can still use Genymotion as a 32bit version under Linux.
This works with this trick:
If you installed Virtualbox on 32bit Windows, you can install the 32bit Windows version of Genymotion.
Now go to the order in which Virtualbox stores its VMs and copy the Genymotion folder into your Linux directory.
Then start Virtualbox for Linux, add a new machine and select the folder where you copied Genymotion before.
After minor adjustments, Genymotion should then run on Linux.
Good luck
Kurt