# Which device should i use in Genymotion to suit my computer properties?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've tried 3 **virtual devices** and when I run any of them a **white screen** is opened without anything inside .

[image]

and i think that the **VirualBox** problem is the reason

[image]

here are my **computer properties**
[image]

[image]

Comment: well for 2 gb ram it'll take time, for you android development try using your mobile as your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered similar issue: [Ubuntu Linux 32bit - not a Genymotion virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189592/ubuntu-linux-32bit-not-a-genymotion-virtual-device/39190434?noredirect=1#comment65723415_39190434)

Genymotion already does not support 32-bit computers, so I suppose that you're running older version or you're trying to run 64-bit version on 32-bit.

With 2GB RAM and 32-bit machine I would have forgotten about any emulator - Genymotion, Android SDK emulator and others.

Look, building small sample application in Android Studio may freeze your computer as it takes more than 1GB RAM and you want to run also an emulator which takes also more then 1GB RAM and I suppose also web browser (Chrome) and other software.

If you really need to work on this pretty weak computer, I suggest you to buy a low-end Android devices and forget about emulator.

It would be good also changing Windows operational system, which seems to me a bit heavy to lite Linux operational system like Lubuntu or Elementary OS.

Hope it will help