# Android Studio, 32-bit Linux, emulator not working even with adb, 32 bit libraries

Tags: android, linux, adb, emulation, 32-bit

Here is the long, sad story of my experiences so far trying to set up an emulator for Android Studio.

My system: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 32-bit

uname -a: 3.19.0-71-generic #79~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 20:07:52 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

**Weird fact**: I can't get into bios on this computer. I have tried every possible key combination and it does not work. I heard that is possibly because of my USB mouse. I plugged into a ps2 port with a ps2 to usb adapter and still could not access bios.

---

**Setup #1:**

Android Studio on Host machine

**Emulator**: Android OS APK on VirtualBox VM, developer mode, bridged networking

trying to connect via adb works ok:

```
$ adb connect 192.168.1.5:5555
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.1.5:5555
```

When I do Run in Studio it finds the VirtualBox. However my app does not make it to the virtualbox and I get lots of errors:

11-27 20:48:01.500 1367-1627/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to set to given group
11-27 20:48:01.500 1367-1627/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Process.setProcessGroup(Native Method)

and

11-27 20:48:01.560 1497-1828/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:28970: (13) open(/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/playlog.db-shm) - 
11-27 20:48:01.560 1497-1828/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/playlog.db'.
                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

etc

---

**Setup #2**

Trying to use Android Studio emulator on 32-bit Linux with KVM.

On my host, I install KVM as per [these instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213272): .

That goes well, (or so I think).

When I open AVD. I create 2 devices:

**device #1**: Android 7.0 x86. When I try to run this device in Studio the emulator does not work and gives a dialog:

KVM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM requires a Genuine Intel processor.

As I said I cannot access bios on this computer so don't know about virtualization. I thought my KVM installation worked but maybe it did not?

**device #2**: Android 7.0 ARM (armabi-v7a). When I try to run this in Studio I get:

~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_19
~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: 1: ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Oh, and I did download [platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip) and replaced ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools with it.

I also set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT = true in my environment as per [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534044/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated-when-attemping-to-r).

I really have been doing everything I could!

I'm dying to try android programming but this is just not working. I need a new computer but that's just not possible right now. I know there is genymotion but I'd prefer to make this solution work as genymotion is not free. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Additionally Genymotion appears to have stopped support for 32-bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189592/ubuntu-linux-32bit-not-a-genymotion-virtual-device so @itgirl may be trying to put a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: That may be true @MorrisonChang. I feel like I've tried everything. In any case it's good to know if I should just give up.